# Why custom validation not workign for reactive form?

Tags: angular

Validator:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function okatoValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
        const valid = /^\d+$/.test(control.value);
        console.log(valid);
        console.log(control.valid);
        return valid ? { okatoValidator: { value: control.value } } : null;
    };
}
```

Using:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    okato: [null, [okatoValidator]]
});
```

Template is:

```
 <input matInput formControlName="okato" />
```

I enter `control.valid` as string value, not numeric, it should be validated wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need closure here since you're not passing any additional parameters to your validator.

Try this version:

```
export function okatoValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const valid = /^\d+$/.test(control.value);

  return !valid ? { okatoValidator: { value: control.value } } : null;
}
```

Comment: That's because `control.valid` property will be updated later.

Comment: It works, what was wrong if I got this from official tutorial?

Comment: In official tuturial they use closure and execute validator function `forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)`